# How can I use javax.crypto to encrypt images?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, javax.crypto

I need a program that could encrypt images, and after a somewhat brief amount of research I stumbled upon the javax.crypto library. I need it be absolutely secure.   Could I use this library, and if so are there any tools that could help me with this?

Comment: An image is a file. Learn how to encrypt and decrypt a file. There is a lot of advice available on the internet. If you have problems with your program, we can help you with it. But you need to write the program first.

Comment: Yes, I would advice you to use [the JCA](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/preface.html), of which the `javax.crypto` package is part of. One often overlooked trick is to use memory mapped files; otherwise I would suggest streaming files using the Java streaming API. Good luck!